# Typo3 Site package not including fluid_styled_content properly?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I have followed the tutorial for making a sitepackage and I am at the point of content mapping.

The problem is, all the text from the rte is being wrapped in `<p>` tags so the output looks like this:

```
<p><h2>A Heading</h2></p>
<p><p>Some Text</p></p>
```

The problem appears to be how fluid_styled_content is included, I have tried both:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">
@import 'EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'
```

The problem goes away if I manually add fluid_styled_content in the typo3 template includes. So how do I include it properly within my site package?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the filename changed. You need to use: `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">`.

You also can use the newer import: `@import 'EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'`

Comment: I tried that too. It's rendering the fluid elements but the text is still double wrapped with <p> tags...